# How to read an image file in node js?

Tags: node.js, fs, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to read an image and text files and upload to `aws s3 bucket` using nodejs `fs module`. I am not using any express server, but plain javascript that calls aws-sdk and uploads items to `aws-s3`.

Here is how my project structure looks like

[image]

Inside s3.js I am trying to read the 2.png and friends.json files,
s3.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const file = fs.readFileSync('../public/2.png', (err)=>console.log(err.message));
```

But this throw and error

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../public/2.png'
```

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could always try an absolute path instead of a relative and add encoding:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const image = path.join(__dirname, '../public/2.png')
const file = fs.readFileSync(image, {encoding:'utf8'})
```

Could also use [upng-js](https://github.com/photopea/UPNG.js/) with a Promise

```
const png = require("upng-js")
const fs = require('fs')

async function pngCode(img) {
try {
       return png.decode(await fs.promise.promisify(fs.readFile)(img)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}

pngCode('.../public/2.png')
```

None of the code is tested wrote on my phone.